# mvc3 create link from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, hyperlink

Is there a way to create a link from a controller and apppend it to a ViewBag ? I been trying but nothing is working

```
 HyperLink hyperl = new HyperLink();
                    hyperl.NavigateUrl = "http://www.example.com/";
                    hyperl.Text = "Here is why..";
   ViewBag.check ="You must register"+ hyperl;
```

**You must register System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink**

I know that I am probably only missing 1 more line but i can't find it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `TagBuilder` and do something like

```
 public static TagBuilder CreateAnchor(string text, string url) 
 {
     var anchor = new TagBuilder("a");
     anchor.SetInnerText(text);
     anchor.MergeAttribute("href", url);
     return anchor;
 }
```

Then pass to the ViewBag Like this

```
 ViewBag.hyperl = CreateAnchor("Here is why..","http://www.example.com/");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing web forms with MVC.  The result will be an abomination.  Just send the URL through the view bag, and use it in the markup in a plain anchor tag:

Controller code:

```
ViewBag.LinkAddress = "...";
```

Markup:

```
<a href="@ViewBag.LinkAddress">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

in **Controller**

```
HyperLink hyperl = new HyperLink();
            hyperl.NavigateUrl = "http://www.example.com/";
            hyperl.Text = "Here is why..";
            ViewBag.check = hyperl.NavigateUrl;
            ViewBag.Text = "You must register";
```

in **View**

```
<a href=@ViewBag.check>@ViewBag.text</a>
```

**or**

```
<a href=@ViewBag.check>You must register</a>
```